# Spring cloud contract test failing to parse JSON correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I am using Spring cloud contract testing to try and contract test an API and can't figure out what is causing my test to fail.

I am using this groovy test file

```
package contracts.api.myClass;

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
  request {
    method 'GET'
    url value(consumer(regex('path/myAPI/(\\w+)')), producer('/path/myAPI/id'))
    headers {
      contentType(applicationJson())
    }
  }

  response {
    status 200
    headers {
      contentType(applicationJson())
    }
    body("""
      {
        "requestId": "id",
        "success": true,
        "datalist": [
          {
            "id": 100,
            "names": ["aaaa", "ffff"]
          }
        ],
        "failureInfo": {
          "failureCode": 100,
          "failureDesc": "failure"
        }
      }
    """)
  }
}
```

The API I am trying to test is generated using swagger code gen 2.0 from the following yaml

```
'/configurator/myAPI/{requestId}':
    get:
      operationId: myAPI
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/GCCX-Request-Context'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/GCCX-TransactionId'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/X-B3-TraceId'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/Accept-Language'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/requestId'
      tags:
        - Configurator
      consumes: [ ]
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Return the response once operation is preformed in BO.
          headers:
            Content-Language:
              description: Describes the natural language(s) of the intended audience for the enclosed entity. Note that this might not be equivalent to all the languages used within the entity-body.
              type: string
            GCCX-TransactionId:
              description: Id to trace the request for debugging purposes
              type: string
            X-B3-TraceId:
              description: Sleuth trace id used to trace multiple requests
              type: string
            X-B3-SpanId:
              description: Sleuth span id used for a single unit of work
              type: string
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MyDataResponse'
        '400':
          $ref: "#/responses/BadRequest"
        '401':
          $ref: "#/responses/Unauthorized"
        '403':
          $ref: "#/responses/Forbidden"
        '404':
          $ref: "#/responses/NotFound"
        '406':
          $ref: "#/responses/NotAcceptable"
        '415':
          $ref: "#/responses/UnsupportedMediaType"
        '429':
          $ref: "#/responses/TooManyRequests"
        '500':
          $ref: "#/responses/InternalServerError"
        '503':
          $ref: "#/responses/ServiceUnavailable"

MyDataResponse:
    type: object
    required:
      - requestId
      - success
      - datalist
      - failureInfo
    properties:
      requestId:
        type: string
      success:
        type: boolean
      datalist:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/DataEntry'
      failureInfo:
        $ref: "#/definitions/FailureInfo"
  DataEntry:
    type: object
    required:
      - names
      - id
```

The groovy test gets autogenerated into the following java test:

```
    @Test
    public void validate_myAPI() throws Exception {
        // given:
            MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // when:
            ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                    .get("path/myAPI/id");

        // then:
            assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
            assertThat(response.header("Content-Type")).matches("application/json.*");

        // and:
            DocumentContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody().asString());
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['requestId']").isEqualTo("id");
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['success']").isEqualTo(true);
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['dataList']").contains("['id']").isEqualTo(100);
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['dataList']").array("['names']").arrayField().isEqualTo("aaaa").value();
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).array("['dataList']").array("['names']").arrayField().isEqualTo("ffff").value();
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['failureInfo']").field("['failureCode']").isEqualTo(100);
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['failureInfo']").field("['failureDesc']").isEqualTo("failure");
```

When I run this test, it fails when trying to get the id field from the data list, with the following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['datalist']
```

Running in debug mode, I can verify that the parsedJson does have the dataList map and the elements contained within, but fails to find them during the test. Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing the issue or what steps I could take to debug the issue? Per company policy, I have changed all use case specific types/apis to generic versions (i.e. myAPI, dataList, etc), so any capitalization issues or naming discrepencies are likely due to my transcribing of the code rather than any issues. All of my component and functional tests pass without issue, so I believe this is just an issue with how I set up my contract test file

Comment: In your contract you are using `datalist` and in the generated test it is `dataList` with capital L? Dont you have a typo somewhere or you just made a mistake while removing sensitive data?

Comment: Just a typo when removing sensitive data. The test runs as intended, just fails to properly parse the returned json